# Estimating Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> $d$ is positive integer.
> $(\mathbb{R}^d, \operatorname{Leb}(\mathbb{R}^d), m)$ is a measure space. Prove that
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{\log(1+ |x|)} dm(x) = +\infty$$

Hint is to use $m(B(0,r)) = c_dr^d$, where $c$ is constant which depends on the dimension.

Can't figure out how to use the hint. Was thinking about using Fatous lemma, but hint won't help with that.

Answer (score 2):

By the monotone convergence theorem,

$$I=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{1}{\ln(1+\lVert x\rVert)}~\mathrm{d}m(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{B(0,n)}\frac{1}{\ln(1+\lVert x\rVert)}~\mathrm{d}m(x).$$

Now notice that the logarithm is an increasing function, and so, for each $x\in B(0,n)$,

$$\frac{1}{\ln(1+\lVert x\rVert)}\geq\frac{1}{\ln(1+n)}.$$

Then

$$I_n=\int_{B(0,n)}\frac{1}{\ln(1+\lVert x\rVert)}~\mathrm{d}m(x)\geq\int_{B(0,n)}\frac{1}{\ln(1+ n)}~\mathrm{d}m(x)=\frac{m(B(0,n))}{\ln(1+n)}=\frac{c_dn^d}{\ln(1+n)}.$$

Now use your favorite method to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_dn^d}{\ln(1+n)}=\infty,$$

from which it then follows that

$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=\infty.$$